# Monterey 12 revert back Login shell

Tags: mac, login

I ve changed the login shell into something i dont know and restart the Mac, it nows stuck in between, only apple logo appears and nothing happens, first aid, cmd+s or V do not worked either.
Ho do you think i can get back to same login shell? I am currently using Monterey 12

Thanks
Ersin

Comment: How did you change the login shell? What Mac is it, exactly?

Comment: It is macbook air 2015, i was searching the users and groups then admin user, advance mode  and trying to find out why my login pictured changed without my intension. then i just changed the login shell and restart

Comment: Ah… beyond my pay-grade, sorry.

Comment: Maybe a better fit for Ask Different: https://apple.stackexchange.com/